# Python regular expression multi patterns, extracting right groups

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I've written a regular expression in Python that should search for season/s and episode/e following by a number. As you can see in my code I have support for all kinds of patterns looking for what I want.

```
import re

episode = re.compile(r"""(?:s|season)(?:\s)(\d+)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?:\s)(\d+)| # s 01e 02
                        (?:s|season)(\d+)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?:\s)(\d+)| # s01e 02
                        (?:s|season)(?:\s)(\d+)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(\d+)| # s 01e02
                        (?:s|season)(\d+)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(\d+)| # s01e02
                        (?:s|season)(\d+)(?:.*)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(\d+)| # s01 random123 e02
                        (?:s|season)(?:\s)(\d+)(?:.*)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?:\s)(\d+)| # s 01 random123 e 02
                        (?:s|season)(?:\s)(\d+)(?:.*)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(\d+)| # s 01 random123 e02
                        (?:s|season)(\d+)(?:.*)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?:\s)(\d+) # s01 random123 e 02
                        """, re.VERBOSE)

test="Hello seinfeld season 01episode 22 foo bar"

match = re.search(episode, test)
print match.group(1), match.group(2)
```

The following code will output `01 22` as expected.
But what if the `test` string would be something like:

```
test="Hello seinfeld season 01 episode 22 foo bar"
```

How would I be able to know which group to use? This is implying I don't know what `test` has for value.

EDIT: Maybe I could check all groups for value and if it's true use that particular group. But this seems like a wrong way of doing it.

Comment: r"""\s*season\s*(\d+)\s*(?:e|x|episode)\s*(\d+)""" works for the example test strings provided and more. Please provide a set of test strings for all cases needed to expand on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about breaking up each of the regex patterns into a list, where each element contains one regex pattern? This would help you organize the regex patterns if you need to add/remove more patterns, while compartmentalizing each variant. You may also want to use regex named groups.

I've modified the original example with additional two changes: 1) individual patterns, and 2) named groups, as such:

```
import re

pattern1 = re.compile(r"""(?:s|season)(?:\s)(?P<s>\d+)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?:\s)(?P<ep>\d+) # s 01e 02""", re.VERBOSE)
pattern2 = re.compile(r"""(?:s|season)(?P<s>\d+)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?:\s)(?P<ep>\d+) # s01e 02""", re.VERBOSE)
pattern3 = re.compile(r"""(?:s|season)(?:\s)(?P<s>\d+)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?P<ep>\d+) # s 01e02""", re.VERBOSE)
pattern4 = re.compile(r"""(?:s|season)(?P<s>\d+)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?P<ep>\d+) # s01e02""", re.VERBOSE)
pattern5 = re.compile(r"""(?:s|season)(?P<s>\d+)(?:.*)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?P<ep>\d+) # s01 random123 e02""", re.VERBOSE)
pattern6 = re.compile(r"""(?:s|season)(?:\s)(?P<s>\d+)(?:.*)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?:\s)(?P<ep>\d+) # s 01 random123 e 02""", re.VERBOSE)
pattern7 = re.compile(r"""(?:s|season)(?:\s)(?P<s>\d+)(?:.*)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?P<ep>\d+) # s 01 random123 e02""", re.VERBOSE)
pattern8 = re.compile(r"""(?:s|season)(?P<s>\d+)(?:.*)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?:\s)(?P<ep>\d+) # s01 random123 e 02""", re.VERBOSE)

patterns = [pattern1, pattern2, pattern3, pattern4, pattern5, pattern6, pattern7, pattern8 ]

test="Hello seinfeld season 01episode 22 foo bar"

for idx, p in enumerate(patterns):
    m = re.search(p, test)
    if m:
        print('MATCHED PATTERN: {}'.format( patterns[idx].pattern ) )
        print('    SEASON:  {}'.format( m.group('s')) )
        print('    EPISODE: {}'.format( m.group('ep')) )
```

output:

```
MATCHED PATTERN: (?:s|season)(?:\s)(?P<s>\d+)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?:\s)(?P<ep>\d+) # s 01e 02
    SEASON:  01
    EPISODE: 22

MATCHED PATTERN: (?:s|season)(?:\s)(?P<s>\d+)(?:.*)(?:e|x|episode|\n)(?:\s)(?P<ep>\d+) # s 01 random123 e 02
    SEASON:  01
    EPISODE: 22
```

Of course, you'll need to add some additional logic to choose which match to take (for example, you can easily choose to take the first complete one), but at least this gives you more transparency to which regex patterns hit.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like an more fluent way of doing it. Didn't know you could name the groups.

Comment: The named groups really come in handy if you have embedded capture groups. Also, you might be able to consolidate all regex pattern variants into fewer patterns with optionals if the number of patterns become unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**  `\s*(season|s)\s*(\d+)(episode|e|x)\s*(\d+)` your match words in group 2 & 4

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\s*(season|s)\s*(\d+)(episode|e|x)\s*(\d+)', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"Hello seinfeld season 01episode 22 foo bar\ns 01e 02\n"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kG6cJ8/1)**